# relationship type,degree, cardinality, optionality terms confusion

Tags: database, database-design

I currently studying database i've seen ***degree*** and ***cardinality*** uses as same term, or in some other degree is defined as no. of entities involved in a relationship and further catogories as unary, binary and trenary.

Some placed degree is defined as The degree of a relationship type concerns the number of entities within each entity type that can be linked by a given relationship type.

Cardinality is minimum and maximun number of entity occurrence associated with one occurrence of
the related entity

cardinality types as `1 to 1` , `1 to many` , `many to many`. or min and max cardinality.

Min degree is optionality and maximum degree is cardinalty.

what is the difference between degree and cardinaltiy ?

In another context cardinality is a number of rows in table and degree is a number of columns.

So what i'm i suppose to write if question is asked "Define cardinality ?".

Can somebody explain ?

Answer (score 5):

Ok here is the explanation

1.Degree. This is the number of entities involved in the relationship and it is usually 2 (binary relationship) however Unary and higher degree relationships can be exists.

2.Cardinality. This specifies the number of each entity that is involved in the relationship 
there are 3 types of cardinality for binary relationships

- one to one (1:1)
- one to many (1:n)
- many to many (n:m)

hope this will clear your mind. Please communicate for more information

Answer (score 4):

**Degree** - number of attributes (columns) in a relation (table)

**Cardinality** - number of tuples (rows) present in a table

See [this](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~chang/156/04reldb.html) for more details.

Comment: I wonder why two explanations here. Both are correct. But why?

Answer (score 3):

To add to the first answer:
Simply

Degree of a Relation - Number of attributes in a relation
Cardinality of a Relation - Number of tuples in a relation.

Can't post the image to show you but you can check out this book to read up more and get a better picture.  Also there is Connolly and Begg - Database Systems, 4th Edition
Reference:

> Elmasri, R., Navathe, S.B., 2011. *Fundamentals of Database Systems*. 6th ed. United States of America: Pearson.

Answer (score 3):

Degree of a Relationship : The number of participating entities in a relationship.  This can be unary, binary, ternary, quaternary, etc

Cardinality : The number of relationship instances an entity can participate in.
Ex: 1:1, 1:Many, Many:N

(Min,Max) notation : Minimum represents the participation constraints while Maximum stands for the cardinality ratio.

Degree of a relation : Number of columns(attributes) in a relation(table).

Answer (score 2):

Degree of a **relationship** is different from degree of a **relation (table)**. Both definitions are likely to get mixed up and cause confusion.

1. Relation in this context *(in relational databases)* is synonym to a "table"
   Whereas,
2. Relationship is synonym to "a connection between tables (relations)".

We have to consider both of these characteristics known as "**degree**" and "**cardinality**" of

1. relations (tables) and
2. relationships

Separately.

---

**1. in a relation (table)**

i) Degree - Number of fields (columns) in relation.

ii) Cardinality - number of records (rows) in relation.

**2. in a relationship**

i) Degree - Number of entities (tables) involved in a relationship (*Unary, Binary, Ternary, N-array*)

ii) Cardinality - Number of connections that each record (row/data) of an entity might establish with the records of other entity. (*One to one, One to many, Many to many*)

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to take note of a distinction when referring to this definition:

- **Degree of a Relationship** differs from,
- **Degree of a Relation**

Good definitions for both have been given above, just take note of this so that the different definitions don't end up confusing you.